# GCP compute engine: how to check instance type (custom Linux) from the instance terminal?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, gcp-compute-instance

I have custom Linux that I can boot up on AWS and GCP.
In AWS I can check EC2 instance type easily from terminal:

```
aws-instance-xyz:/ # dmidecode -s system-product-name
m6i.4xlarge
```

I would like to be able to check instance type of compute engine in GCP however *dmidecode* command is of no use here:

```
gcp-instance-xyz:/ # dmidecode -s system-product-name
Google Compute Engine
```

I have to be able to check the instance type using a command in terminal. I can't install GCP cli on that linux environment so any *gcloud/gutils* commands are not an option.

Answer (score 1):

As per this [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/detect-compute-engine#use_operating_system_tools_to_detect_if_a_vm_is_running_in) `sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name` is used to detect if the VM is running in Compute Engine.

To get the metadata details you need to use the `curl` command as mentioned in this [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/querying-metadata#programmatically_query_metadata).Use the below command to get instance type:

```
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/machine-type" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

Output:
[image]

It will be flexible if you use gcloud and adding here the [installation document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) for your reference.

Comment: I know about the curl option but I hoped there is another solution for that.

Comment: Other options are using gcloud only as per document.

Comment: @pykaczka - write a simple Python script to fetch the machine-type. Now that you know how there are endless possibilities.